# What is the most convenient method to clone my application?

Tags: marklogic

I would like to find the most convenient way to clone my application(including every related contents and settings) which running on my local laptop,
to another MarkLogic Server running on my different laptop.

Based on the documentation, there were multiple alternatives to
replicate, backup/restore databases, but which is the easiest?

Also, I found export features in Configuration Manager,
should I must use this feature too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is a combination of your Content Database, Modules Database and associated Application server/s.

Exporting the configuration with [Configuration Manager](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/config_manager) will cover the specific settings for the server, databases and app servers.  Backup/Restore and replication will cover the data.

Alternatively, if your application is not too big, you may be able to shut down MarkLogic, and copy the installation directory between the systems.

- For Windows: `C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data`
- For Linux: `/var/opt/MarkLogic`

This will probably meet your needs if you only need to do this once or twice, but it you plan on doing this regularly, you should use an automated deployment tool such as [ml-gradle](https://developer.marklogic.com/code/ml-gradle), which can handle [exporting](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Exporting-resources) and deploying most, if not all, of your application resources.

Comment: You may be able to export most, if not all, of your application's resources via ml-gradle as well - see https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Exporting-resources